# Does most topographic data come with Z Coordinates, and if so how do you put them in a QGIS map?

Tags: qgis, hydrology, rivers, catchment

I am trying to create a map of the rivers in a large catchment. When I try to 'fill the sink', mine makes it as if the surface is flat. My rivers are just squiggly lines.

It doesn’t look like it has understood the Z-values of the DEM correctly. It’s basically assigning everything as a low elevation and giving you a nonsensical catchment.

How can I get my Z coordinates?

I am following this video...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Ub0c7Ss-T4

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the DEM, as well as your settings for the converion tool.

Comment: Please tell a bit more about what you were doing: what tools, what settings etc. Otherwise, we can just speculate.

Comment: Have you merged your DEMs?

Comment: Yes I have merged my DEMS. Not yet in this picture, but I have merged them.